# How to obtain transcendental equation from matrix with determinant?

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, matlab, computational-mathematics, quantum-mechanics

So, I'm completing the Kronig-Penney model, a quantum mechanics problem, from scratch. I obtained four equations that must be held true, and I wrote them as a matrix where the determinant is equal to zero.

I know this much to be correct, as I arrived at the same Matrix as Wikipedia:

[Kronig-Penney Model Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx0t2.png)

I also know that this matrix is satisfied when a specific transcendental equation is satisfied. The equation is given below:

[Transcendental Equation (Solution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwljw.png)

I know there must be a way to solve the matrix and arrive at this equation, but I haven't had success. I have tried using MATLAB, but am told that no explicit solutions can be found (which is fine, but how do I find the implicit transcendental?).

I would really appreciate anyone's input on whether I can solve this problem, with coding or without.

Thank you, everyone, for your help :)

Comment: Probably you should calculate the determinant of the matrix and equate it to zero. After simplifications you will get your transcendental equation.

Comment: According to Mathematica, the determinant of your matrix simplifies to $$4 e^{-i (a-2 b) k} [2 \alpha \beta (\cos(a k)-\cos((a-b) \alpha) \cos(b \beta))+(\alpha^2+\beta^2) \sin((a-b) \alpha) \sin(b \beta)]. $$ Setting this equal to zero yields the desired transcendental condition. So the real problem here is how to simplify this determinant in a manageable way.